# Manual 2008 Ford Ranger won't go into gear sporadically

Tags: ford, clutch, shifting, ranger

I recently purchased a used 2008 Ford Ranger.  Not long afterwards I began having trouble getting it into gear.  I took it in and the clutch was worn out and needed to be replaced. The slave and master cylinder were replaced as well. I now have a new clutch that works well most of the time but sporadically the clutch stops working and I either have great difficulty shifting gears or cannot get it into gears at all.  This can last for five minutes or a whole day of driving.  Then it goes back to shifting well.  I've brought it back to the mechanic numerous times and he cannot find anything wrong with it.  I am hoping someone may have some insight into this problem.

Regards

Comment: I'm wondering if the clutch master/slave wasn't bled correctly.

Comment: I wonder that as well... I don't like fords hydraulic clutch systems so I've always converted mine to cable...

Comment: Also when they installed your clutch did they change throw out bearing? It could be a issue of the last clutch was badly worn/grinding heavy....

Comment: Does the clutch pedal feel softer than before?

Comment: I had to do this on my son's truck about a month ago.  He has the 2006.    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=91IYY_YENRw

Comment: If it's occasional I doubt it is air in the system. When the clutch was changed did they replace the pilot bearing/bushing? If not, that would explain it being occasional if the bearing binds and the releases. Put it in gear with the engine off, push the clutch and start the engine. See if that makes it stop by forcing it to get past a bad spot I the bearing.

Answer (score 1):

Try re-bleeding the clutch system. I had a 1990 ford ranger that I pulled the trans on. When I put it back in and bled the clutch, I tried to put it in gear but wouldn't go, so tried bleeding it again and that fixed it. If it still has air pockets in the line it won't shift well, or may not shift at all. I'm with Dee, I don't like the hydraulic clutch system that Ford has.